# C Programming: Write name 15 times without loop?

Tags: c, loops

Im only in my 2nd week of intro to programming in C. So far all we've done is hello world and learned about data types and how many digits/bytes/etc are in each one and simple input/output things like basic math.

My assignment for the week (posted online by my professor) is to write a program that will output my name to the screen 15 times.

Based on what I've learned so far, how am I supposed to do this besides simply typing printf("MyName\MyName\n...etc") 15 times?

It feels like this assignment has nothing to do with what we've learned so far? Is it likely he may have given us the wrong assignment or something? I just don't even know where to begin for this.

(*please keep in mind that i'm supposed to do this based off of what he's taught us so far*)

Comment: I think you are correct in that you simply need to printf your name 15 times. I imagine your *next* assignment will be to do the same but using a looping construct, showing you the benefit of loops.

Comment: Thank you. It just seems strange that our first week we did Hello World, and now our second week we're still doing essentially the same thing. It's just weird learning all about data types, but then having our assignment be on something based off of the first week's lesson. Oh well!

Comment: @Eric It is quite common for assignments to be out of date with the lectures by a week or two.

Comment: @usar: Because 3 people upvoted it and 1 person downvoted it.

Comment: Maybe sneak by with `puts("my name to the screen 15 times.");`.  Only works if prof is light hearted.

Answer (score 5):

One can use macro expansion to repeat a literal a number of times, but this is likely beyond the scope of your current progress in the class.

```
#define REPEAT3(X) X;X;X;
#define REPEAT5(X) X;X;X;X;X;
#define REPEAT15(X) REPEAT5(REPEAT3(X));

int main()
{
  REPEAT15(printf("hello world\r\n");)

  return 0;
}
```

Here are some additional links regarding macros:

[Tutorials - C programming tricks @ cprogramming.com](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cpreprocessor.html)
[C preprocessor @ wikipedia (this is the thing that does the work of replacing/expanding macros)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor)

Answer (score 4):

Recursion;

```
void myname(int countdown) {
   printf("My name is Eric\n");
   if (--countdown > 0) myname(countdown);
} 
int main() {
   myname(15);
}
```

Comment: @specializt I don't think so, since he/she has only learnt to display "Hello World"s and similar things, I don't think this answers the OP's question

Comment: that may be true for normal schools - but in my country there are schools in which these levels of learning are actually expected

Comment: If the rule is "using things already covered", then if loops haven't been covered yet, I rather doubt recursion has been.

Answer (score 2):

If you know `if` statement and labels too which are basic then you can do something like this:

```
int counting=15;
evil_01:
printf("MyName\n");
if (--counting!=0) goto evil_01;
```

This isn't part of the answer, but this is bad practice to use labels like that.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another Recursion:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   if (argc <2 || argc > 16 ) return 0;
   printf("My name is %s\n", argv[1] );
   return main(argc+1, argv);
}
```

Comment: That's creepy. I like it!

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define x printf("My Name\n")

int main()
{
  x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ( void ) {
    return (printf("%s", "\
MyName\n\
MyName\n\
MyName\n\
MyName\n\
MyName\n\
MyName\n\
MyName\n\
MyName\n\
MyName\n\
MyName\n\
MyName\n\
MyName\n\
MyName\n\
MyName\n\
MyName\n\
") > 0);
}
```